# Android open gallery with local (from 'res' folder) images

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

Is it possible to open Android Gallery for image selection (like ACTION_PICK intent for images from camera and other apps) but make it to show ONLY images stored locally in our app ('res' folder)?
The use case for this is to provide option to select app background from provided images.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. App assets are not available to standard Gallery application

Comment: That's not technically true. Resources and assets are publicly read-only. That's how the home screen launcher can get your activity icons and labels, for example. Now, in this case, there's no standard way to get an arbitrary "gallery" app to browse some set of image resources from your app, but that's more of a protocol issue, not a lack of technical capability.

Comment: For some reasons I did not wanted to go too deep into the issue answering this question. Unfortunately "No, it is not possible" was to short to meet SO limits. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The standard "gallery" `<intent-filter>` does not include support for app resources at all.

> The use case for this is to provide option to select app background from provided images.

Use your own `ViewPager`, or `GridView`, or [`StaggeredGridView`](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView), or [`AndroidStaggeredGrid`](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid), or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Closest I can think of is using a custom content provider, and maybe using ACTION_PICK with a uri that your content provider responds too?

This is more of a guess than an answer.